# How to use ng-bind/ng-bind-template for HTML5 Data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, custom-data-attribute, ng-bind-html

In my code I have a button and I'm attaching the data to it by using the HTML data attribute and Angular.js expression to show the notification to it. The code is like this

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-link navbar-btn" 
        data-notifications={{tweetCount}}> 
    <span class="twitter-edit" ></span>
</button>
```

But the bad of using expression can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03). So the obviously the solution is to use either `ng-bind` or `ng-bind-template`.

But how do I do this for the data attribute? In my CSS I have a style declared for `data-notification` as

```
[data-notifications]:after {
    content: attr(data-notifications);
    position: absolute; 
    top:1.75em;
    right: -0.5em;
}
```

The above code to display `{{tweetCount}}` is working for me. The only problem is, for a split second `double curlies` are actually displayed to the user while the page is loading. To resolve this `ng-bind/ng-bind-template` is recommended to use. But in my case I have to apply it to data-attribute tag.

Comment: did you try to use `ng-attr-data-notifications` ?

Comment: So the problem is that you can't get the styling to work with the ng-bind/ng-bind-template?

Comment: It seems like `ng-attr-data-notifications` is working on page load. As after using this, i'm no more getting the curlies while page load.

Answer (score 0):

I think your just missing the quotes around your handle-bars.

```
<button type="button" 
    class="btn btn-link navbar-btn" 
    data-notifications="{{tweetCount}}"> <---quotes around the handle-bars
  <span class="twitter-edit" ></span>
</button>
```